# Integration push firebase notification on ionic 3

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3

I am trying to use firebase push, my code is correct to give the build I put a console.log to see if it has permission if everything is correct, but when I send the notification through the firebase. nothing comes for me..

app.component.ts

```
.then((res: any) => {

    if (res.isEnabled) {
      console.log('We have permission to send push notifications');

    } else {
      console.log('We do not have permission to send push notifications');
    }

  });
  const options: PushOptions = {
android: {},
ios: {
   alert: 'true',
   badge: true,
   sound: 'false'
},
windows: {},
browser: {
   pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
}
};

const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);


pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => console.log('Received a notification', notification));

pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => console.log('Device registered', registration));

pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error))
```

Config.xml

```
<platform name="ios">
    <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
</platform>
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.1.3">
    <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="1064226096335" />
</plugin>
```

Console in xcode

```
01:30:14.735620-0300 Myapp[4390:567615] FCM Sender ID 1064226096335
2018-06-08 01:30:14.735644-0300 Myapp[4390:567615] Using FCM Notification
2018-06-08 01:30:14.897536-0300 Myapp[4390:567453] FCM token is null
2018-06-08 01:30:14.898198-0300 Myapp[4390:567453] We have permission to send push notifications
2018-06-08 01:30:14.902557-0300 Myapp[4390:567453] Push Plugin register success: <c1e83f2d 3a9c1fd2 0115d192 4f3d27ce 53c217d3 4b861176 ff65cbac c4ceae9d>
```

Firebase

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what happens, but you can take a look at my working code on GitHub https://github.com/dalenguyen/ionic-firebase-notification

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look thanks for responding

Comment: Would you by any chance not have a project in IOS?

Comment: No, I am using a Windows machine.

Comment: mano, I downloaded your project I changed the sender id and I changed the bundle id widget id = "com.lucasteste.push" and it did not work I did not receive anything

Comment: I gave build on my cell phone ...

Comment: Is it an Ios or android phone? Does it work on the browser?

Comment: Is it an Ios or android phone? Does it work on the browser